# jQuery help with unbind then bind again after animation sequence

Tags: jquery, events, bind, unbind

I have the following js function and I would like to prevent anything from happening and queueing once the click event has happened. Then when the function ends allow the click event to happen again.

```
$("#tweet_activate a").click(function(){    
if($('body').hasClass('home')) {
$(this).parent().stop(true,true).animate({top: "+=154"}, 400).delay(1200).fadeOut();
} else {
$("#int_comp").animate({width: "+=157"}, 100);
$(this).parent().stop(true,true).animate({top: "+=154"}, 400).delay(1200).fadeOut();
}
$("#tweet_text").delay(400).animate({right: "+=56"}, 400);
$("#tweet").delay(900).animate({right: "+=214"}, 400);
$("#tweet_deactivate").delay(1200).fadeIn();
$("#tweet_text p, #tweet_text span, #tweet #links").delay(1200).fadeIn();
$("#eye").delay(600).fadeOut();
return false;
});

$("#tweet_deactivate a").click(function(){
if($('body').hasClass('home')) {
} else {
$("#int_comp").animate({width: "-=157"}, 400);
}
$("#tweet_text p, #tweet_text span, #tweet #links").fadeOut();
$("#tweet").stop(true,true).animate({right: "-=214"}, 400);
$("#tweet_text").delay(400).animate({right: "-=56"}, 400);
$(this).parent().delay(900).animate({top: "-=154"}, 400).delay(200).fadeOut()
.delay(600).animate({top: "+=154"}, 100);
$("#tweet_activate").animate({top: "-=154"}, 500).delay(650).fadeIn();
$("#eye").delay(1000).fadeIn();
return false;
});
```

The site is here - http://danielhollandphotography.com/

If you click on the 'plus' sign on the right icon grid you'll see the sequence happen. If you click the icon mid way through you'll see it fire again.

Thanks, Matt

Comment: Also, looking over your code; you realize you can specify callback functions for most of the 'timed' stuff. So instead of having everything 'delayed' you would just callback to the next animation or fade effect.

Comment: Hi I know it could be more efficient but not sure how. If you are able to, feel free to give a small example. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a small check to the element.Once you start the animation set a bool to true, on click make that your first check

```
var animating = false;
$("#tweet_activate a").click(function() {
    if (animating !== true) {
        animating = true;
        if ($('body').hasClass('home')) {
            $(this).parent().stop(true, true).animate({
                top: "+=154"
            }, 400).delay(1200).fadeOut();
        } else {
            $("#int_comp").animate({
                width: "+=157"
            }, 100);
            $(this).parent().stop(true, true).animate({
                top: "+=154"
            }, 400).delay(1200).fadeOut();
        }
        $("#tweet_text").delay(400).animate({
            right: "+=56"
        }, 400);
        $("#tweet").delay(900).animate({
            right: "+=214"
        }, 400);
        $("#tweet_deactivate").delay(1200).fadeIn();
        $("#tweet_text p, #tweet_text span, #tweet #links").delay(1200).fadeIn();
        $("#eye").delay(600).fadeOut(function() {
            animating = false; // this is a guess. but place this where ever the animation is stopping. 
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

This should work. Give it a try.

```
$("#tweet_activate a").click(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.attr("is-animated") !== "true") {
        $this.attr("is-animated", "true");
        if ($('body').hasClass('home')) {
            $this.parent().stop(true, true).animate({
                top: "+=154"
            }, 400).delay(1200).fadeOut();
        } else {
            $("#int_comp").animate({
                width: "+=157"
            }, 100);
            $this.parent().stop(true, true).animate({
                top: "+=154"
            }, 400).delay(1200).fadeOut();
        }
        $("#tweet_text").delay(400).animate({
            right: "+=56"
        }, 400);
        $("#tweet").delay(900).animate({
            right: "+=214"
        }, 400);
        $("#tweet_deactivate").delay(1200).fadeIn();
        $("#tweet_text p, #tweet_text span, #tweet #links").delay(1200).fadeIn();
        $("#eye").delay(600).fadeOut(function() {
            $this.attr("is-animated", "false");
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

you can see the key is the attr("is-animated"); I cannot do the check in the main button because that has already defined the click event before I have applied the attribute. Strange. Ohh well, if you wrap the contents of the click event in a if statement like I did in the previous example it works. Unlike the previous example however I am attaching a attribute to the anchor tag here and reading it to see if it is in a state of animation. This way you can have multiple elements with this type of event 'blocking'

Comment: Works a charm. I'm also trying it on another similar piece of code but the code ends with $("#content_area").stop(true,true).delay(800).animate({top: "-=57"}, 400);
    return false;
 }); 

How would I add the last part of code from your fix to this. I couldn't get it to work myself...

    function() {
            animating = false;
        });
    }
    return false;
});

Comment: On second thought, and I can't believe I didn't think of this first. You can use the `:animated` selector in jquery . give me a minute and I will update with a new way of writing the same script.

Comment: the last solution I am adding a class to each link while the click event/motion is happening. Then after your last animation I remove the class to allow the link to be clicked again. You can use classes or attributes. for attributes read up on .attr() and attribute contains selectors. Attributes will probably also be better. jeeze, i'm 0/2 today. you risk conflicts when you add and remove arbitrary classes like that.

Comment: Hi, neither of your updates worked!! The original code works a treat. Just need to get it working for my other block. Kinda works. You can see the full code here -http://danielhollandphotography.com/wp-content/themes/dd/js/script.js Look at the block straight after the tweet function. The eye_close click event doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, sorry was busy last night. Give me a minute to look at this some more.